# What does ?? and ? means in SWIFT

Tags: swift

I saw this code style:

```
var Text = textField.text ?? ""
```

Does the ?? also means:

```
textField.text = ""
```

Also another coding style I saw was:

```
let switch: CGFloat = self.switchControl.on ? 1 : 0
```

What does the ? mean here in this scenario.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html ..

Answer (score 0):

`? :` is the inline `if` syntax, often used to shorten conditional statements. This

```
let switch: CGFloat = self.switchControl.on ? 1 : 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
let switch : CGFloat
if self.switchControl.on {
    switch = 1
} else {
    switch = 0
}
```

`??` means if not null, return the expression, otherwise return the alternative value. It's equivalent to:

```
var Text = textField.text != nil ? textField.text! : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` is the ternary operator. It has the general form of `condition ? true-value : false-value`. You can think of it as a shorthand for writing an `if`  statement - the condition is evaluated, and if it's true the `true-value` is returned. Otherwise, the `false-value` is returned. In your example: `self.switchControl.on ? 1 : 0`, `self.switchControl.on` is evaluated, and if it's `true`, `1` is returned, otherwise `0` is returned.

`??` is the `nil` coalescing operator. If the first argument is not `nil`, it's returned, and if it is, the second argument is returned. In your example, the expression `textField.text ?? ""`, would return `textField.text` if it's not `nil`, or `""` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is known as the **nil coalescing operator**, and it's equivalent to writing:

```
var Text: String
if textField.text != nil {
    Text = textField.text!
} else {
    Text = ""
}
```

which in English words means: evaluate the left expression, if it's not nil unwrap and return it, otherwise return the right expression.

The `?:` **ternary conditional operator** is a similar but different operator: it evaluates a logical expression (at the left of the `?` operator), if it's true the result of the expression at the left of the ':' operator is returned, otherwise it returns the result of the expression at the right.

The basic difference between the 2 operators is that the former checks for nil/not nil when determining the expression to return, in the latter case it's the logical expression at the left of the `?` operator determining which of the following 2 expression values to return.